# Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition when setup Magento 2.0 (0.1.0-alpha107)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, pdo

Today I setup a version of magenta 2.0 (build 0.1.0-alpha107). But the process has stucked at 23% with error:

```
Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause'
```

Here are some pieces of error log:

```
Module 'Magento_Sales': 
Include /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Magento/Sales/sql/sales_setup/install-2.0.0.php 
[ERROR] exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/setup/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Could you please take a look at the error, and suggest me a solution?

Comment: The previous mysql versions does not allow default on UPDATE for date time data type other than TIMESTAMP. I suppose you have mysql version less than 5.5  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to MySQL 5.6

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/782

Magento 2 Requirements: https://github.com/magento/magento2#magento-2-system-requirements